# Convert images to DOC\RTF

Tags: pdf, latex

My CV is written in LaTeX using [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv), and I have a script that converts it to PDF whenever I need to send an updated copy.

However, some employers require Microsoft Word (or RTF) CV. I have converted the PDF into images, and manually pasted them into a DOC file.

Is there a way to convert a series of pictures into a `.doc` file, each in a separate page?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution: convert your latex document to rtf using [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

A correct conversion is not sure, because it only understand a subset of latex.

It is available in the official Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I'll try it out.